# Table not rerendering when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a table with checkboxes which rerenders a table as the checkboxes are clicked. This works fine, except for when all the checkboxes are set back to unchecked. Then the table does not rerender.

Controller:

```
public List<Case> allCases;
public List<Id> selectedCaseIds{get;set;}
public List<CaseWrapper> caseList = new List<CaseWrapper>();

public PageReference getSelected(){
    selectedCaseIds.clear();
    for(CaseWrapper cw : caseList){
        if(cw.selected){
            selectedCaseIds.add(cw.ca.Id);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<CaseWrapper> getCases(){
    for(Case c : allCases){
        caseList.add(new CaseWrapper(c));
    }
    return caseList;
}

public class CaseWrapper{
    public Case ca{get;set;}
    public Boolean selected{get;set;}

    public CaseWrapper(Case c){
        ca = c;
        selected = false;
    }
}
```

VF page:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="checkedOne">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" rerender="mytable"/>
        </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!c.ca.CaseNumber}" headerValue="Case Number"/>
    <apex:column value="{!c.ca.RecordType.Name}" headerValue="Record Type"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Do you have like a header checkbox that you are checking to deselect all the records at once and that's when the table doesn't rerender? I don't see the js part of the VF page that would do that for you, and that may be what your issue is???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was actually to do with the table I was trying to re-render, which I didn't post in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Give ID to your Table.

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c" id="mytable">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="checkedOne">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" rerender="mytable"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!c.ca.CaseNumber}" headerValue="Case Number"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.ca.RecordType.Name}" headerValue="Record Type"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Check it whether it is Working or Not

Comment: The id myTable refers to another table on my Visualforce page, that's the one I'm trying to rerender.